# Excel VBA - How to pull Data from a file in Protected view / restrict personal macros

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to VBA, but I like to think that I'm a quick learner. At work, I have a network directory to store all of my department's files.

I'm putting together a record of some past work, so I wrote a script that searches an open workbook and returns the information I want (most files follow the same base format, so it just uses the find function and some loops).

When I open the files from the directory, they are in *protected view*, which is Ideal so that I don't change any of the old data. The issue is that I can't seem search or access that workbook (with my script) unless I enable editing on it.

I began opening copies of the books to avoid changing the original, but found another problem: Many of these old files also have their own macros in use, but they were build for an older system/program and prompt an error message constantly if opened. I'm not looking to edit any of the old files' macros.

Although I don't save the copies (once my script is run, I don't need them anymore), I've also noticed that if I enable editing on the copy, anytime I open the original again (to check a value, or find project details) - even if in read-only - it defaults to opening it (original) for editing, rather than keeping it read-only.

The section of code that selects the book (and the summary sheet within) is:

```vb
Dim bk As Workbook, bkN As String
For Each bk In Workbooks
    bkN = CStr(bk.Name)
    If bkN = WrkBk Then
        Dim wkSht As Worksheet, wsN As String
        For Each wkSht In bk.Worksheets
            wsN = wkSht.Name
            If wsN = "Summary" Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next wkSht
        Exit For
    End If
Next bk
```

where `WrkBk` is the name of the file to be referenced (it was having problems just pulling directly). To solve this problem, I was wondering:

**Is there any way to have my script run through a file opened in protected mode?**
*Or, alternatively:*
**Is there a way to only allow macros/scripts that I wrote to run (the old files & macros were created by other people before my time here)?**

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** *corrected that files were originally in protected view.*

Comment: "The issue is that I can't seem search or access that workbook (with my script) unless I enable editing on it" - I'm not sure that's going to be reproducible without more detail.

Comment: You should limit your question to *one* question. How can you accept an answer if someone answered only the first. Please take the https://stackoverflow.com/tour to learn how SO works

Comment: That said, it's no problem accessing the data of a workbook that was opened read/only. If you get an error, you need to show us the code and what exact problem you have. And set `Application.EnableEvents = False` before opening a Workbook with Macros to avoid that those are executed.

Comment: I run macros on Read-Only files all day every day. I share files with co-workers, so its easier to open things in Read-Only if I don't need to edit them. I've never encountered a situation where being Read-Only blocked any VBA methods.

Comment: the other macros from the documents I'm accessing are outdated and will not run unless repaired; I'm not editing them in any way. I'm also adjusting the question to give more information. My code works fine on any open, editable book, but those I open without editability are not included in the default Workbooks collection.

Answer (score 1):

After digging a little more, I found how to search for open files in protected view and edited my search loops:

```vb
If PWC > 0 Then
    Dim Npro As Integer
    Do While Npro < PWC
        Npro = Npro + 1
        Set bk = Application.ProtectedViewWindows(Npro).Workbook
        If bk.Name = WrkBk Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
```

then an else that searches for the file if it's not in protected view, before returning to my summary sheet search loop:

```vb
Dim wkSht As Worksheet, wsN As String
    For Each wkSht In bk.Worksheets
        wsN = wkSht.Name
        If wsN = "Summary" Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wkSht
```

And now it allows me to pull data from the sheets without breaking protected view.
**Thank you all for your help!**
*I'm also open to any suggestions you have to simplify this system.*